# How to limit the number of retrieved characters from a database field in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Consider a passage (~400 characters) in a database table(text).
Like

> There is only one more week to Easter. I have already started my
>   holiday. The idea of visiting my uncle during this Easter is
>   wonderful. His farm is in this village down in Cornwall. This village
>   is very peaceful and beautiful. I have asked my aunt if I can bring
>   Sam, my dog, with me. I promise her I will keep him under control. He
>   attacked and he ate some animals from her farm in October. But he is
>   part of the family and I cannot leave him behind.

but i need to retrieve only limited characters from that like ~150 characters only.

> There is only one more week to Easter. I have already started my
>   holiday. The idea of visiting my uncle during this Easter is
>   wonderful. His farm is in this village down in Cornwall. This village
>   is very peaceful...

Is there any function in rails or only `truncate(:limit,:option{})` function for that output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a model `Passage` with a field `text`, you can [select specific field](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) (and use SQL functions within) like this:

```
passages = Passage.select("id, LEFT(text,10) as text_short, CHAR_LENGTH(text) as text_length")
# => [#<Passage id: 1>, #<Passage id: 2>, #<Passage id: 3>]
passages.first.id
# => 1
passages.first.text_short
# => "There is o"
passages.first.text_length
# => 453
```

Comment: why dont you prepare a db view for this one

Answer (score -1):

Why not get the whole string and only use the first 150 characters? I doubt it will slow things down much at all.

`somehow_access_string[0...150] + '...'`

Comment: It may not impact performance much at small scales, but there's certainly no reason to fetch the entire string if you only need a portion of it. This isn't a good generic solution.

Comment: interesting, didnt know that. Thanks!